# AttributeError: module 'sklearn.mixture' has no attribute 'GMM'

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am attempting to run the following Python project:

https://github.com/huanghe314/Text-Independent-Speaker-Indentification-System

It depends on `sklearn.mixture.GMM`, but fails to find that module despite the fact that I have `sklearn` installed. The error it gives is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/User/PyCharmApp/Text-Independent-Speaker-Indentification-System-master/Code/main.py", line 85, in &lt;module&gt;
    p_weight[m] = training.Training_feature_Weight(Name[m] + '.wav')


File "C:\Users\User\PyCharmApp\Text-Independent-Speaker-Indentification-System-master\Code\training.py", line 24, in Training_feature_Weight
    Weight_training = Training_info.GMM_Model_Weight()
  File "C:\Users\User\PyCharmApp\Text-Independent-Speaker-Indentification-System-master\Code\GMM.py", line 31, in GMM_Model_Weight
    weight = mixture.GMM(n_components = self.M, min_covar = 0.01, n_init = 10).fit(self.features).weights_
```

I'm running Python 3.6.

Comment: Hi, please show some of your python code as well.

Comment: And, then, please post it as [edit] of your question.

Answer (score 8):

`sklearn.mixture.GMM` is no longer available in current versions of `sklearn`, as per the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/0.18/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GMM.html#sklearn.mixture.GMM):

> Deprecated since version 0.18: This class will be removed in 0.20. Use
>   `sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture` instead.

Given that, I believe your options are either to change the code to use `GaussianMixture` or downgrade your version of `sklearn`.